# Android Studio, keep getting "Screen Recorder Error"

Tags: android, android-studio, video, screen-recording

I was trying to record my application, but the screen recorder did not work.

Tried reconnecting my real device, restarting it, restarting Android studio but nothing worked.
I'm using: Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 8
I was getting the error bellow: